# Embedd hosted jquery in html in IIS vs locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, iis, asp-classic

I am developing a web application and when I try to embedd the "hosted" jquery does not work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

But if I download it and call it locally like this it works:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

It seems like when a script is called from an URL "http://..." it doesn't work when I try to go the main application:

```
https://myserver/appname/index.htm
```

I'm using ASP and Microsoft IIS. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: because of mixed content http and https.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are getting [mixed content warnings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent). The browser is not loading the http when you are on https.

Change the url to

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

which will load it to https and there should be no mixed content issue. The `//` is a protocol relative url so it will load the file in whatever protocol the page is loaded in.